# install older version of therubyracer(v0.9.10) gem on mac mojave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, therubyracer

It's my very first time with ruby on rails.

I cloned this project from github.

https://github.com/fredwu/angel_nest

it took me a while to setup and figure out things.
i'm having a lot of compatibility issues as this project was made a long time ago.

when i do "bundle install"
I get this error and bundler stops.

> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>           /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for main() in -lobjc... yes creating Makefile
>
> make compiling v8_external.cpp clang: warning: argument unused during
>   compilation: '-rdynamic' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
>   v8_external.cpp:10:9: warning: unused variable 'references'
>   [-Wunused-variable]   VALUE references;
>           ^ 1 warning generated. compiling v8_exception.cpp clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] v8_exception.cpp:10:16: warning:
>   unused variable 'stack' [-Wunused-variable]   static void* stack[20];
>                  ^ 1 warning generated. compiling v8_function.cpp clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling v8_handle.cpp clang:
>   warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling v8_array.cpp clang:
>   warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling v8_try_catch.cpp clang:
>   warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling v8_v8.cpp clang: warning:
>   argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] v8_v8.cpp:22:49: warning: implicit
>   conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int'
>   [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
>       V8::SetFlagsFromString(RSTRING_PTR(string), RSTRING_LEN(string));
>       ~~                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:674:6:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
>        RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:670:6:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
>        (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ v8_v8.cpp:22:49: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision:
>   'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
>       V8::SetFlagsFromString(RSTRING_PTR(string), RSTRING_LEN(string));
>       ~~                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:675:28:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
>        RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
>        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~ 2 warnings generated. compiling v8_callbacks.cpp clang: warning: argument unused during compilation:
>   '-rdynamic' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling v8_string.cpp
>   clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] v8_string.cpp:18:73: warning:
>   implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int'
>   [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
>       return rr_v8_handle_new(string_class, String::New(RSTRING_PTR(str), RSTRING_LEN(str)));
>                                             ~~~~~~                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:674:6:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
>        RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:670:6:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
>        (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ v8_string.cpp:18:73: warning: implicit conversion loses integer
>   precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
>       return rr_v8_handle_new(string_class, String::New(RSTRING_PTR(str), RSTRING_LEN(str)));
>                                             ~~~~~~                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:675:28:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
>        RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
>        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~ v8_string.cpp:23:79: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int'
>   [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
>       return rr_v8_handle_new(string_class, String::NewSymbol(RSTRING_PTR(str), RSTRING_LEN(str)));
>                                             ~~~~~~                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:674:6:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
>        RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:670:6:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
>        (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ v8_string.cpp:23:79: warning: implicit conversion loses integer
>   precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
>       return rr_v8_handle_new(string_class, String::NewSymbol(RSTRING_PTR(str), RSTRING_LEN(str)));
>                                             ~~~~~~                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:675:28:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
>        RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
>        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~ 4 warnings generated. compiling v8_message.cpp clang: warning: argument unused during compilation:
>   '-rdynamic' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling rr.cpp clang:
>   warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] rr.cpp:48:1: warning: control reaches
>   end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] } ^ rr.cpp:151:44: warning:
>   implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int'
>   [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
>       return String::New(RSTRING_PTR(value), RSTRING_LEN(value));
>              ~~~~~~                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:674:6:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
>        RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:670:6:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
>        (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ rr.cpp:151:44: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision:
>   'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
>       return String::New(RSTRING_PTR(value), RSTRING_LEN(value));
>              ~~~~~~                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/divyanshuverma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:675:28:
>   note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
>        RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
>        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~ 3 warnings generated. compiling v8_weakref.cpp clang: warning: argument unused during compilation:
>   '-rdynamic' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling v8_script.cpp
>   clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling v8_date.cpp clang: warning:
>   argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling v8_debug.cpp clang:
>   warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling v8_value.cpp clang:
>   warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] v8_value.cpp:100:9: warning: unused
>   function 'ToInt32' [-Wunused-function]   VALUE ToInt32(VALUE self) {
>           ^ 1 warning generated. compiling v8_object.cpp clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] v8_object.cpp:77:19: warning: unused
>   variable 'proto' [-Wunused-variable]
>       Handle proto(rr_rb2v8(prototype));
>                     ^ 1 warning generated. compiling v8_locker.cpp clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] v8_locker.cpp:45:5: warning: control
>   reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
>       }
>       ^ v8_locker.cpp:85:5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
>       }
>       ^ 2 warnings generated. compiling v8_template.cpp clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling v8.cpp clang: warning:
>   argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] compiling v8_context.cpp clang:
>   warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument] linking shared-object v8.bundle
>   clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/divyanshuverma/angel_nest/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4/lib/libv8/build/v8/libv8.a'
>   make: *** [v8.bundle] Error 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/divyanshuverma/angel_nest/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.9.10
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/divyanshuverma/angel_nest/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.9.10/ext/v8/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.9.10), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.9.10'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

i've tried all approaches available on stackoverflow for this method but none works!
is there any way to override the requirements of this gem make changes such that project works on the newer version of therubyracer gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version is locked only by `Gemfile.lock`, which means that there're probably no specific requirements in project itself.

You can try updating just this gem without full `bundle update` via: `bundle update therubyracer`, most probably newer version will do ok.

Comment: Thank you for the insights! I modified the lock file and then "bundle update therubyracer" command worked!

Comment: lockfile is modified by bundler, you do not have to do it youself, the latter command tells bundler to ignore lock for specific gem and install the newest that fits other requirements